# PHP - Clone object and call method in same statement

Tags: php, datetime, object

Is it possible to clone a DateTime Obj and call a method all in the same statement? I know it can be done on object instantiation. I tried a test script on cloning but it didn't work.

```
<?php 
// instead of 
$nextDay = clone $startDate;
$nextDay->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));

// something like this instead
$test = ['test' => (clone $nextDay)->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))];     
?>
```

Comment: Cant help you with no code. Also you're superunclear about what you want to copy and what method you want to call.

Comment: Sorry let me edit it, just so eager to get a solution.

Answer (score 4):

It is in PHP7, but not in PHP5

```
$startDate = new DateTime();
$endDate = (clone $startDate)->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));

echo $endDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

will work in PHP7

**EDIT**

However, you can get start and end date simply in PHP5 by taking advantage of DateTimeImmutable, where the `add()` method leaves the original value unchanged, but return a new object:

```
$startDate = new DateTimeImmutable();
$endDate = $startDate->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));

echo $startDate->format('Y-m-d'), PHP_EOL;
echo $endDate->format('Y-m-d'), PHP_EOL;
```